# Long Post Title Misaligning Grid with Featured Image

Tags: post-thumbnails, get-the-title

I'm putting together a [grid with the featured images](https://www.japanistry.com/test/) as the background and the post title above.

It works fine, but when the post title spreads over two lines the entry before or after is moved up/down and the grid is misaligned. I can't work out why it's doing this so any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

My CSS:

```
.FacetFeatured {
width: 32.9%;
height: 140px;
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: 4px;
background-size: 100% 140px;
}

.FacetFeatured img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.FacetHeadingIMG {
font-weight: bold;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
}
```

This is the code in the template:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>
<?php echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $_post->ID ) . '" title="' .     esc_attr( $_post->post_title ) . '">';?>
<div class="FacetFeatured" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>')">
<div class="FacetHeadingIMG"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( get_the_title() );?></a></div>
</div>
<?php echo '</a>';?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options:

### Use ellipsis by pure CSS

Add this rule to your CSS file. This will add `...` whenever the title is longer than its parent DIV.

```
.FacetFeatured a{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis
}
.FacetFeatured{
    max-width: 100px // Change this to fit your grid
}
```

This is only done by using CSS.

### Strip the title by PHP

You can also strip the title by some custom length to make sure it's never broken into two lines. Use this code to do so.

```
function title_max_charlength($charlength, $title) {
    $charlength++;
    if ( mb_strlen( $title) > $charlength ) {
        $subex = mb_substr( $title, 0, $charlength - 5 );
        $exwords = explode( ' ', $subex );
        $excut = - ( mb_strlen( $exwords[ count( $exwords ) - 1 ] ) );
        if ( $excut < 0 ) {
            $output = mb_substr( $subex, 0, $excut );
        } else {
            $output = $subex;
        }
        $output .= ' ...';
        return $output;
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}
```

Now, you can call your title like this:

```
echo title_max_charlength( 100, esc_html( get_the_title() ) );
```

And it will return 100 characters of your title. Change 100 to whatever prevents your lines from breaking.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response and kind help. Not sure why it occurs in the first place, but your suggestions worked.

Comment: @GeckoBoy You're most welcome. Because if the line breaks, the horizontal and vertical adjustment of the elements will be different. This way you can prevent the line from breaking.